# Web-scraping a website which uses javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I will try to keep this short; I am trying to scrape information from exactly this website : http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/uldaman/Dus/statistic#21:152

That list includes an item "Highest 2 man personal rating" followed by a number. The number is what I'm looking for. Where exactly is the number stored and how can I obtain it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Terrible question. What have you tried so far? How are you fetching the data? What programming language are you using? The only one you have tagged in `javascript`. Is that what you are writing? Where are you running it? Windows Scripting Host? Node.js? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering you are using jQuery:

```
$('#cat-152 dt').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == "Highest 2 man personal rating" }).siblings('dd').text()
```

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is lame ..

Comment: Why would you assume that the OP is "using jQuery"? The `javascript` tag says *Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected*. This also assumes that the OP has already built a system to fetch the page, generate a DOM from it and execute the JS attached to the page (and there is no evidence of that in the question).

Comment: This will not work unless you are the owner of the source for the page, cross scripting security will be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    host: 'eu.battle.net',
    path: '/wow/en/character/uldaman/Dus/statistic/152'
};

var count = 0;

http.get(options, function(res) {

    var data = "";

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
       var d = data;
       var payload = d.toString();
       var finder = "<dt>Highest 2 man team rating</dt><dd>";
       var indexOfHighest2Man = payload.indexOf(finder);
       var indexOfClosingDD = payload.indexOf("</dd>", indexOfHighest2Man);

       var count = payload.substr(indexOfHighest2Man,  indexOfClosingDD - indexOfHighest2Man);
       count = count.replace(/\s/g, "");
       count = count.replace("<dt>Highest2manteamrating</dt><dd>", "");

       //***************** Here is the answer *******************
       console.log('Highest 2 man rating ',count);
       //********************************************************
    })


}).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
    });
```

Comment: This is a node.js scraper, run it.  It works!